# How can I define `search-whitespace-regexp` so it accepts a Unicode "no-break space"?

Tags: whitespace, isearch

I'm writing a lot of Markdown for input to pandoc, so my files contain a lot of Unicode non-breaking spaces (U+00A0).  I'd like those to search as whitespace with `isearch-forward`, so I tried adding the character to my `search-whitespace-regexp` variable.  But it doesn't work.  I suspect there might be a UTF-8 issue somewhere.

I've tried

```
(set (make-local-variable 'search-whitespace-regexp)
 "[ \t\r\n\f~\u00a0]+")
```

and I've also tried just hard-coding the character between the square brackets.  Neither works.  By contrast, I can search the `~` character as white space just fine---so I know something is working.

How can I persuade Emacs that the U+00A0 should be accepted as a space character, for purposes of search?

I'm running Emacs 24.5, a stock Emacs from Debian jessie.

**Edited to add**: following a comment from steveooo, I've determined that

```
M-x eval (search-forward-regexp "cise[ \t\r\n\f~\u00a0]6")
```

correctly finds the string I'm looking for, but `isearch-forward` still does not work.

**Edited to add**: In Emacs 25, nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Data point: When I test (using re-builder) a regexp "[\u00a0]+" on a buffer that contains non-breaking spaces, it matches properly. This is with emacs 26.0.50 (built from upstream source in the last month or so).

Comment: This is odd - calling `(search-forward-regexp "[ \t\r\n\f~\u00a0]+")` works as expected so it doesn't look as though it's a problem with the regexp itself. I wonder if this means that it's a problem with isearch - which I assume is what you mean by searching?

Comment: @stevoooo it is very odd.  I have edited to add that using `M-x eval` with your command works for me, but using `M-x search-forward-regexp` does not.  I feel like there ought to be a clue there, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: "enter the same regexp in the minibuffer (without the double quotes)" - I don't think that prompt interprets character escape syntax, i.e., you're searching for `cise[ trnf~u0a]6`.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks.  Removed that reference.

Comment: I took a quick look through isearch.el and it seems to just end up calling re-search-forward, which AFAICT works perfectly well matching a regexp containing \u00a0. That may mean the problem is somewhere in isearch.el?

Comment: I think the problem *is* in `re-search-forward`: `(let ((search-spaces-regexp "[ \t\r\n\f~\u00a0]+")) (re-search-forward "( " nil t))` finds the `~` but not the non-breaking space. I suspect some code assumes ascii characters where it shouldn't.

Comment: Ah, well perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem.  I don't think there's any guarantee that `re-search-forward` uses `search-spaces-regexp` - the docs just say "Some commands use this for user-specified regexps" which isn't very helpful.  isearch does, but re-search-forward is a lower level routine and I suspect that it might not be using it.  If you do something like `(re-search-forward "hello[\u00a0]+world")` against the appropriate text then it will match across the non-breaking space, which is why I think the problem may not be in re-search-forward.